# How to choose the default font with font-display: fallback

Tags: css

I use a specific font that & I wanna set A default font if the font loading is too high.

So I try:

```
font-display: fallback;
```

It looks to work well (didn't check compatibilities but it doesn't matter) but it is possible to choose the default font ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fallback font is whatever comes after the custom font:

```css
font-family: CustomFont, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

See also [this article](https://css-tricks.com/font-display-masses/) on CSS-Tricks.